# Unit Testing for a Python RESTful API

Tags: python, rest, api, unit-testing, python-requests

What's the best way to perform Unit Testing for a RESTful API that includes email functionality (lost passwords, user activation) in Python?

Everything is done via HTTP POST / GET and at this time, authentication isn't involved.

Should I just use the `requests` library and manually do everything I want?  Is it possible to use `requests` to automate the parts of my Unit Testing that involves email?

Comment: You should unit tests your handlers without the HTTP overhead first. Everything else is not really a unit test but rather some kind of integration test.

Comment: if you use http, it's not a unit test. generally, if you test anything else than one single class, in the case of a rest api all the url routing, data handling whatsoever - it's not a unit test.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Often the web framework that you use to implement the REST api will also offer unit testing support. For example:

- Flask: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/testing/
- Django: http://django-testing-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/views.html

These test classes are shortcuts which plug the request directly into the framework's Url dispatcher. That saves you the hassle of finding a free port, spawning a "real" server and connecting the http client from your unit test.

As for the e-mail sending: I would mock that part in the `TestCase.setUp` method. Just change the reference to the e-mail sending module / class to another module/class which loops the outgoing e-mail back to the unit test for evaluation rather than e-mailing.

Comment: These tools might be helpful if you have a WSGI app but the framework doesn't have good unit testing support: http://wsgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/testing.html.

Comment: @Freek Wiekmeijer, the Flask URL is broken.